# (Phalcon) How to redirect (Phalcon\Http\Response) from static method in model

Tags: php, redirect, static, phalcon

I'm trying to create a reusable static function which redirects if true.
This function will be in a model.

```
public function checkEmtpy(ResultsetInterface $resultset)
{
    $di = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault();

    if (empty($resultset->toArray())) {

        $di->get('flash')->error('Page not found.');
        return $di->get('response')->redirect('content');

    } else {

        return false;

    }
}
```

I tried several ways to redirect but I can't get it to redirect from the model.

What can I change to make this work or isn't this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is against MVC principle to do redirects in models. The redirect has to be done in the Controller. What you should do is return only the status from your model only. Something like this:

```
// Model
public function checkEmtpy(ResultsetInterface $resultset)
{
    return empty($resultset->toArray());
}

// Controller
public action someAction()
{
    $isEmpty = (new YourModelName)->checkEmtpy($someVariable);
    if ($isEmpty === true) {
        return $this->response->redirect(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the redirecting in model working but immediately understood it wasn't practical. I'm now checking the resultset and redirecting with a function in a controller for reusable purposes.